# Platform constraints rejecting the host (matching) platform

Tags: bazel

I'm trying to use platform constraints on a target:

```
cc_test(
    name = "library_test",
    srcs = ["library_test.cc"],
    deps = [":library"],
    target_compatible_with = [
        "@platforms//cpu:x86_64",
        "@platforms//os:linux"
    ]
)
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Dependency chain:
//platforms:library_test (1f7c4b)   <-- target platform (@local_config_platform//:host) didn't satisfy constraints [@platforms//cpu:x86_64, @platforms//os:linux]
```

Which I find confusing, considering that this should be correct. How do I print what the values in `@local_config_platform//:host` are?

I do have the `--incompatible_enable_cc_toolchain_resolution` flag turned on.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75415060/2263152 is a better answer than mine. Flagging this question as duplicate seems wrong because it was before that, but also the other one has a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can find this in `bazel-out/../../../external/local_config_platform/constraints.bzl` (relative to your Bazel workspace).

Similar paths also work for any other external repository (`@something` is in `bazel-out/../../../external/something`). [Repository rules](https://bazel.build/extending/repo) create these folders via various mechanisms, and being able to look at the result is very helpful for debugging.

Comment: I was unable to find local_config_platform/constraints.bzl nor see what constraints are in it.