# How to inspect @local_config_platform//:host?

Tags: bazel

I'm running into some toolchain issues, with errors like:

```
INFO: ToolchainResolution:     Type @io_bazel_rules_go//go:toolchain: target platform @local_config_platform//:host: Rejected toolchain @go_sdk//:go_linux_amd64-impl; mismatching values: linux, x86_64
INFO: ToolchainResolution:   Type @io_bazel_rules_go//go:toolchain: target platform @local_config_platform//:host: No toolchains found.
```

but I believe I am running on x86_64 and Linux, but that would be made clear by inspecting the generated constraints.

This was mentioned [earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74240658/platform-constraints-rejecting-the-host-matching-platform), but I was unable to find said-generated file.

And in case it ever helps anyone else, I'm running popos.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `query --output=build` to dump the rule:

```
$ bazel query --output=build @local_config_platform//:host
# /home/user/.cache/_bazel_cache/bf5544946d234767647dbf413a7bc3c9/external/local_config_platform/BUILD.bazel:4:9
platform(
  name = "host",
  constraint_values = ["@platforms//cpu:x86_64", "@platforms//os:linux"],
)
```

The comment line even tells you were to find the original generated `BUILD` file.